# Selenium: Cannot tick checkbox

Tags: c#, selenium

Trying to put a tick mark in a checkbox, but getting an 'OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException' exception.

DOM(There are multiple rows and a checkbox on each):

```
<td style="text-align:center">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk_divAccountsGrid_37193" class="k-checkbox">
    <label for="chk_divAccountsGrid_37193" class="k-checkbox-label">
      ::before
  </label>
</td>
```

Test code:

```
driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//label[starts-with(@for, 'chk_divAccountsGrid')]"))[1].Click();
```

and

```
driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("[id^='chk_divAccountsGrid']"))[1].Click();
```

The input has a dimension of 0x16 and the label has a dimension of 18x0, but the '::before' has a dimension of 16x16 but don't know how perform a click() on it.   Is there another way putting tick mark in the checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

Because the checkbox and label width or height is 0, so we can think they size is 0. When element size is zero, user can't see it on page, selenium api simulate user experience, it will throw `ElementNotVisibleException` to make it close to user experience.

To fix your problem, you can't use selenium `click()` to operate element from frontend, but use selenium `executeScript()` to inject and execute a javascript snippet to operate element from backend.

```
label = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//label[starts-with(@for, 'chk_divAccountsGrid')]"))[1].Click()

driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", label) // if label not work, pass-in checkbox
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this is typically due to a page not yet being loaded fully when the driver attempts to click the box. I would identify the element with :

```
[FindsBy(How.How=XPath, Using="//label[starts-with(@for, 'chk_divAccountsGrid')]")] 
public IWebElement chkAccountsGrid {get;set;}
```

Then attempt clicking it as follows:

```
    // Click Checkbox
    public void ClickCheckbox(IWebElement element)
    {
        WaitUntilClickable(element, 10);
        element.Click();
        // element.SendKeys(Space);
        // element.SendKeys(Enter); 
        Console.WriteLine( element + " Clicked");
    }

    // Wait Until Clickable
    public static void WaitUntilClickable(IWebElement elementLocator, int timeout)
    {
        try
        {
            WebDriverWait waitForElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            waitForElement.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(elementLocator));
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element: '"+element+"' was not found in current context page.");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A `<label>` tag won't accept a `click()` but an `<input>` tag will. To put a tick mark in the checkbox as per the given `HTML` you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@class='k-checkbox' and starts-with(@id,'chk_divAccountsGrid_')]")).Click();
```